# Como puedo actualizar periódicamente notificaciones en pestaña del navegador

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

Tengo el siguiente código:

en mi globo de notificaciones

```
  <li class="notifications new">
    <a id="push" href="{{route ('notificaciones.index') }}">
        @if ($count = Auth::user()->UnreadNotifications->count())
            <span class="badge" >{{$count}}</span>
        @endif
            <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
    </a> 
  </li>
```

y para que se me actualice dicho globo tengo el siguiente script

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var refreshId =  setInterval( function(){
            $('#push').load(' #push');//actualizar
            }, 5000 );
        });
```

en mi etiqueta titulo

```
@if ($count = Auth::user()->UnreadNotifications->count())
<title>({{$count}}) SOANDES</title>
@endif
```

Lo que deseo es que, asi como se me actualiza mi globo de notificaciones, se actualice dicho valor cada minuto en el titulo que lleva mi pagina en la pestaña del navegador.

Les agradezco de antemano por su ayuda.

aqui una imagen de la vista actualmente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @Wilmer, lo que puedes hacer ahí es colocare un **id** el titulo y con el metodo **.html()** de jquery ir lo actualizando. Esto lo harías de la misa forma que estas llenando la campana. lo que en lugar de usar **.load** usaras **.html()**

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @YoelRodriguez. He hecho lo que me dijiste pero al llegar una nueva notificación, me muestra el nombre del id que le asigne a mi titulo. que podre estar haciendo mal?

Comment: Buscando en internet encontre este link que explica como cambiar el title desde jquery aqui te lo dejo, esta en stacoverflow en  ingles espero que te sirva. [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180103/jquery-how-to-change-title-of-document-during-ready/11171548)